# How to click on the "publish item" button using vba + selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, excel

So I am trying to automate inputting some "ads" in my webpage using Excel and VBA +selenium. So far I have managed to fill in all the info I need, but I can't click the button "publish item". Every line I have written for this action gives me an error 7 in execution time //insufficient memory.

The web is https://edenlife.es/osclassified/item/new

The code I have written is:

```
Sub Pruebas()

    ' Assuming you are using Selenium Basic for Excel (SeleniumWrapper)
    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "MicrosoftEdge", "Path\To\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" 'Provide the correct path to MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
    
    obj.Get "https://edenlife.es/osclassified/item/new"

'DropDownMenu for Category
    ' Find the category dropdown element and click it
    obj.FindElementByCss(".simple-cat span.text").Click
    ' Find and click the desired category option by its text
    obj.FindElementByCss(".option.root[data-id='96']").Click ' Change the data-id accordingly

'Insert Title
 obj.FindElementById("titleen_US").SendKeys "TESTING"


' Introduce a small delay of 500 milliseconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'DropDownMenu for location = missing


' Switch to the iframe containing the TinyMCE editor
    obj.SwitchToFrame obj.FindElementByCss("#descriptionen_US_ifr")

    ' Input text into the TinyMCE editor
    obj.FindElementByCss("#tinymce").SendKeys "This is a test description."

    ' Switch back to the main content
    obj.SwitchToDefaultContent

' Introduce a small delay of 500 milliseconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    
    ' Continue with other actions
   
    obj.FindElementById("cityArea").SendKeys "Santander"
    obj.FindElementById("address").SendKeys "Calle San Luis 7"
    obj.FindElementById("contactName").SendKeys "Edenlife"
    obj.FindElementById("contactEmail").SendKeys "Edenlife@edenlife.es"
    
' Introduce a small delay of 500 milliseconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

   'DropDownMenu Edenred
     ' Select option from "Accepts EdenRed" dropdown
    obj.FindElementById("meta_accepts_edenred").AsSelect.SelectByText "Yes" ' Change "meta_accepts_edenred" to the actual ID of the dropdown
    obj.FindElementById("meta_vegan").AsSelect.SelectByText "Yes"
    obj.FindElementById("meta_playground").AsSelect.SelectByText "Yes"
    obj.FindElementById("meta_web").SendKeys "www.test.com"
    obj.FindElementById("meta_parking").AsSelect.SelectByText "Paid (Street)"
   
' Introduce a small delay of 500 milliseconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    ' Find and click the "Publish item" button // IVE TRIED ALL THESE:
    obj.FindElementByCss(".buttons-block .inside .box .row button.btn.alpBg").Click
   'obj.FindElementByCss(".btn.alpBg").Click
   
    'Other method:
    'obj.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", obj.FindElementByCss(".buttons-block .inside .box .row button.btn.alpBg")
   'obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[contains(text(), ' Publish item')]").Click
   
End Sub
```